# License question for dungeon dragon like game

Tags: licensing

I want to create a dungeon and dragon based games.  Basically, I want to take the rules and some basic aspects of the game.  I have some old dungeon dragon handbook notes.  I won't be able to recreate the entire system (version 4 of dungeon dragons) but will I be breaking any license if I do that.

I figure that the concept of dungeon and dragons has been used in RPGs for decades.

And this is kind of a general license question?  Are ideas such as this copyrighted?

Comment: This is not really a programming question.  If you are serious, you need to ask a lawyer - nobody here can offer binding legal advice.

Comment: [link a](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20/welcome) [link b](http://kotaku.com/#!5428864/hasbro-sues-atari-over-dd-license-atari-responds) may be useful. i don't especially know about the licensing itself however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know some of WOTC's stuff is part of the OGL, which means anyone can use it, that, I think, includes the d20 system, you'd have to look in the books to see what particular elements are under a private license